# Memberships - Receipt (on-line): multiple "amount" rows under Membership Fee

Tags: civimember, message-templates, receipts

The "Memberships - Receipt (on-line)" template, the code below causes 3 "amount" rows and a Membership Type label doesn't seem to be shown, also there is no "Membership Type" token available for the template. A bug perhaps?

*CiviCRM  5.70.2 - 5.71.1, Wordpress.*

```
      {foreach from=$lineItems item=line}
      <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>
          {if $line.membership_type_id}
            {ts 1="{membership.membership_type_id:label}"}%1 Membership{/ts}
          {else}
            {ts}Contribution Amount{/ts}
          {/if}
        </td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>
          {$line.line_total_inclusive|crmMoney:'{contribution.currency}'}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {/foreach}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to make a few template changes.
Line 80:

```
 {foreach from=$lineItems item=line}
      <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>
         {if {membership.membership_type_id}}
               {ts 1=$line.label} %1 {/ts}
          {else}
            {ts}Contribution Amount{/ts}
          {/if}
        </td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>
          {$line.line_total_inclusive|crmMoney:'{contribution.currency}'}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {/foreach}
```

Line 168:

```
{ts}Total Amount{/ts}
```

Now it looks right (changes highlighted in green) - both membership Type label and an Optional Donation label, plus, the "Amount" becomes the "Total Amount".

Would've supposed a patch, but the template here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/master/xml/templates/message_templates/membership_online_receipt_html.tpl?ref_type=heads  has totally different code so, perhaps, is not the right place.

[image]